# É possível criar uma function que receba como parâmetro um JSON e percorra este JSON salvando os dados em uma tabela, porém filtrando

Tags: json, postgresql

É possível criar uma function que receba como parâmetro um JSON e percorra este JSON salvando os dados em uma tabela, porém filtrando o Json.
Hoje está inserindo json direto sem filtro.

Exemplo:

Estou recebendo esse json como entrada na proc.:

```
    {
    "Documento": {
        "Apolice": [
            {
                "cdEmpresa": "01",
                "cdSucursal": "010",
                "cdCarteira": "431",
                "dsTipoDocumento": "A",
                "idApolice": "501741",
                "idEndosso": "000000",
                "ItemProp": [
                    {
                        "idLocal": "000001",
                        "dsEndereco": "RUA RUA RUA",
                        "dsComplemento": "CASA",
                        "dsCidade": "BELO HORIZONTE",
                        "dsUF": "MG"
                    }
                ],              
                "ItemAuto": [
                    {
                        "nrItem": "000001",
                        "cdModelo": "0017664",
                        "nmMarca": "VOLKSWAGEN",
                        "nmModelo": "TRENDLINE 1.0 FLEX 12V 5P",
                        "nmTipo": "FOX",
                        "aaFabricacao": "2016",
                        "aaModelo": "2017"
                    },
                    {
                        "nrItem": "000001",
                        "cdModelo": "0017664",
                        "nmMarca": "VOLKSWAGEN",
                        "nmModelo": "TRENDLINE 1.0 FLEX 12V 5P",
                        "nmTipo": "FOX",
                        "aaFabricacao": "2016",
                        "aaModelo": "2017"
                    },
                    {
                        "nrItem": "000001",
                        "cdModelo": "0017664",
                        "nmMarca": "VOLKSWAGEN",
                        "nmModelo": "TRENDLINE 1.0 FLEX 12V 5P",
                        "nmTipo": "FOX",
                        "aaFabricacao": "2016",
                        "aaModelo": "2017"
                    },
                    {
                        "nrItem": "000001",
                        "cdModelo": "0017664",
                        "nmMarca": "VOLKSWAGEN",
                        "nmModelo": "TRENDLINE 1.0 FLEX 12V 5P",
                        "nmTipo": "FOX",
                        "aaFabricacao": "2016",
                        "aaModelo": "2017"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Cliente": [
            {
                "cdCliente": "1",
                "dsTipoDocto": "P",
                "nrCpfCnpj": "919191919292",
                "nmCliente": "JOSE JOSE JOSE"
            }
        ],
        "EnderecoCobranca": [
            {
                "dsEndereco": "RUA RUA RUA",
                "nrEndereco": "280",
                "dsComplemento": "",
                "dsBairro": "INTEGRAÇÃO",
                "dsCidade": "PAROBE",
                "dsUF": "RS"
            }
        ],
        "Mensagem": []
    }
}
```

E gostaria de filtrar o Array de `Apolice`, no caso os campos: `cdEmpresa`, `cdSucursal`, etc..., e inserir dentro dos seus respectivos campos.

Minha Proc é :

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.tabela(entrada json)
  RETURNS void as

        'INSERT INTO schema."tabela" 
        SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset 
        (null::schema."tabela", $1);'

  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui realizar um procedimento onde eu leio o arquivo Json de entrada;
Insiro em uma tabela temporaria;
Depois faço insert novamente em outra tabela inserindo somentes os campos que eu tiver no
result da query utilizando funções json Postgre.
Exemplo:

-- resultTeste onde grava o resultado do select realizado no json:

```
  resultTeste := (select dados ->'Documento'->'Apolice' from _teste as result);
```

--Insere os registro do resultTeste nos campos correspondentes do Json da table temp:

```
INSERT INTO _testeDados select * from json_populate_recordset(null::_testeDados,resultTeste);
```